# Remainders in structure $r^1, r^2, ..., r^{p - 1}$ modulo $p$ for two primes $r, p, r < 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I just experimented with expressions in the form $r^1, r^2, ..., r^{p - 1}$ modulo $p$, where $r, p, r < p$ are primes.

Let's say $1 < n \leq p - 1$ is the smallest number such that $r^n \equiv 1 \pmod p$ (obviously $n$ can't be 1).

**1. Does this *n* exist for every prime $r, p, r < p$?**

Now, I noticed something amazing. Namely, if and only if $n = p - 1$, numbers $r^1, r^2, ..., r^n = r^{p - 1}$ gives all remainders (between $1$ and $p - 1$) modulo $p$. **2. How to prove this**?

(Of course, other direction is obvous: if $1 < n < p - 1$ then it will be $r^{n + 1} \equiv 1 \cdot r = r \pmod p$ and we wouldn't have all remainders modulo $p$. )

I also noticed that $n$ has to be *divisor* of $p - 1$ (**3. is this true and how to tell which divisor?**), so we have simple *cyclical repeating of remainders* if $n < p - 1$.

This is what I computed:

Modulo 5:
$2^1 \equiv 2, 2^2 \equiv 4, 2^3 \equiv 3, 2^4 \equiv 1$
(all remainders: 2, 4, 3, 1).

Modulo 7:
$2^1 \equiv 2, 2^2 \equiv 4, 2^3 \equiv 1, 2^4 \equiv 2, 2^5 \equiv 4, 2 \equiv 1$
(cyclical repating of remainders: 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1).

**4. why some times there are all remainders, and some times cylical repeating, i. e. why $n$ is sometimes $p - 1$ and sometimes less than $p - 1$?**

Also, I have very minimal knowledge of primitive roots (basically I know just a definition), so please take that in consideration. Thanks!

Comment: Cf. [Multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), in particular, the Properties section, and also the associated [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Comment: @Will Jagy, thanks. Obviously I must check these basic things up on my own if I want to progress. Also, I read you recommend that book by Lehman. Do you think it's a good book for self-learning? I am going to college this fall, so I want to have some reasonable knowledge about Number theory, although it's 2nd year subject.

Comment: Well, for a beginner, the book by Weissman probably fills in more detail. I like that he does the Conway topograph for binary quadratic forms. Lots of activities, lots of pictures

Comment: Great. Where can I find out the contents of the book?

Comment: Yes. See Fermat’s little theorem. $r$ doesn’t have to be prime, just not divisible by $p.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, oh yes - obviously! But, why there is sometimes $n < p - 1$? (See my computations.) And, in that case, why $n$ is divisor of $p - 1$?

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/   with excerpts   https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1616567209959/mbk-105/~~FreeAttachments/mbk-105-pref.pdf  

https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1616567209959/mbk-105/~~FreeAttachments/mbk-105-toc.pdf

https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1616567209959/mbk-105/~~FreeAttachments/mbk-105-prev.pdf

https://bookstore.ams.org/cdn-1616567209959/mbk-105/~~FreeAttachments/mbk-105-index.pdf  Currently on sale

Comment: Thank you, it looks very interesting. I am having 19th birthday this summer, so this would be a nice present for myself! :)

Comment: The smallest $n$ is always a divisor of $p-1.$ Sometimes it is less than $p-1.$